# How to hide quicklaunch

Tags: powershell, quick-launch, hidden

I am writing powershell scripts and have been trying to find a solution for this but haven't been able to. I just wanted to find out how to hide the quicklaunch using powershell. Is it a property of the sitecollection or a site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant hide it using powershell as it is based on core.css. if you want to suppress it you have to put javascript/css to hide navigation and refrenced it in MasterPage.

Comment: Thanks. I found this link that helped with the solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg144573(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It should work for you.

$spSite = Get-SPSite  http://intranet.contoso.com

$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb();

$spWeb.QuickLaunchEnabled = false;

$spWeb.Update();

Comment: It doesn't work, only does half the job. Every solution that I found, asks to do it in css. Have a look at my link in the comment for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to hide the quick launch in a particular page in a site its better to use css for it. Just open the site using sharepoint designer move to the exact page where you want to hide the Quick Launch. On the Top of the Sharepoint Designer you can find a button called Advance Mode Click on it and now you be able to edit the code within the master pages. Within any content add the following style.

```
<style type="text/css">
Div.ms-titleareaframe {
height: 100%;
}
.ms-pagetitleareaframe table {
background: none;
}
    </style>
```

Thanks.